# Package used for engagement api twitter

Tags: twitter

Is there any package used in php for hitting the following api in twitter.

```
https://data-api.twitter.com/insights/engagement/historical
```

Comment: That is a premium API endpoint. Do you already have a premium agreement with Twitter?

Comment: Actually I want the package for this api.

Comment: Yes, but even if we provided you with a programming SDK, you can only access this endpoint if you have a paid agreement with Twitter.

You can see a curl command for hitting this endpoint at https://t.co.recipes